# MySql inserting on multiple table using BEGIN and COMMIT java

Tags: java, mysql

Is this query possible on java?

```
"BEGIN;"
+ "INSERT INTO product(code, name, description, category_id) "
+ "VALUES(?,?,?,?);"
+ "INSERT INTO inventory_item(quantity, price, product_id) "
+ "VALUES(?,?,LAST_INSERT_ID());"
+ "COMMIT;";
```

I used it on a `PreparedStatement` and it really eating my time just to figure out the error my `dbUnit` said there is an error on the statement

```
com.example.dao.exception.DataAccessException: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in 
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO product(code, name, description, 
category_id) VALUES('00003','lemon ' at line 1
    at 
com.example.dao.InventoryDaoImpl.addInventoryItem(InventoryDaoImpl.java:126)
```

I can't print the PreparedStatement on the console I tried

```
PreparedStatement statement = 
        connection.prepareStatement( FIND_INVENTORY_ITEM_BY_PRODUCT_CODE_QUERY );
System.out.print( statement );
```

Can you guys give me a hand figure out the error?

Comment: i suppose, you have `END` at the end of your begin-end block? ;)

Comment: I already have the `COMMIT`

Comment: Does the same query work when you try it manually on the mysql server?

Comment: There must be `END;` at the end of block - otherwise it's syntax error

Answer (score 0):

May not be *the* way, but this has always worked for me:

```
List<String> sqlStatements = new ArrayList<String>();
// stuff your statements into this list
// (I'm often reading them from some file. The file often
// contains blank lines, comments and semicolons, which I
// strip out.)
Statement stmt = null;
try {
    dbConn.setAutoCommit(false);
    stmt = dbConn.prepareStatement();
    for ( String sql : sqlStatements ) {
        logger.debug("\t"+sql);
        stmt.addBatch(sql);
    }
    stmt.executeBatch();
    dbConn.commit();
} catch ( Exception e ) {
    // handle exceptions
} finally {
    // close statement
}
```